# How do I make this code more DRY? (Multiple css animations playing on scroll over)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have the usual animation.css file and a few divs that are in the same place but have different animations attached to them. They should animate at the same time (when scrolling over the page) but differently, that is.

This is the code I use for ONE animation:

```
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);

    // Get the scroll position of the page.
    var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
    var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    // Get the position of the element on the page.
    var elemTop = Math.round( $elem.offset().top );
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

// Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation() {
    var $elem = $('.sp-effect1');

    if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
        // Start the animation
        $elem.addClass('fadeInLeft');
    } else {
        $elem.removeClass('fadeInLeft');
    }
}

// Capture scroll events
$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkAnimation();
});
```

The problem is, I only know how to get the other animations playing at the same time by copying this code and calling the variables different things, and then running it again and again, just calling different classes (`fadeInRight` and `fadeInDown`) on the different divs (`sp-effect2` and `sp-effect3`).

As this method isn't very DRY and frankly a bit stupid, how can I achieve the same result within the same code block instead?

*Edit: The code I pasted here above is DRY, since I didn't want to paste the actual bad code which is just a repeat of what is pasted here above. You have to read my request to understand what I mean.*

Comment: Looks pretty dry to me.  I don't see any repeats in the code.

Comment: Sorry, bad title perhaps since I changed my mind mid-post and decided not to post the repeated code. Just imagine the same code pasted over and over again just with different variable names...

Comment: maybe can consider to apply OOP technique, create a function with accept div class name and animation style.

Comment: yes in that case OOP is for you.  Object oriented programming.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is that you want multiple versions of checkAnimation that each operate on different objects and use different class names, then you can just factor those into arguments to the `checkAnimation()` function and pass in different versions.  You can also use `.toggleClass()` to simplify the add/remove class logic:

```
// Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation(selector, cls) {
    var $elem = $(selector);
    $elem.toggleClass(cls, isElementInViewport($elem));
}

// Capture scroll events
$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkAnimation('.sp-effect1', 'fadeInLeft');
});
```

Then, if you want to use this same code for different objects with different class names, you can just add them like this:

```
// Capture scroll events
$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkAnimation('.sp-effect1', 'fadeInLeft');
    checkAnimation('.sp-effect2', 'fadeInRight');
});
```